# Multiple frames in a Java application

Tags: java, jframe

Just need some quick guidance -

I have a main frame, and I want some smaller frames inside of it that can be dragged outside of the main frame (potentially onto multiple monitors). When dragged back in, they should not be hidden behind the main frame when the main frame is clicked on.

I'm unclear about what I should be using... JFrames? Frames? Windows???

I used two JFrames, but the lesser JFrame gets pushed behind the main JFrame when I click on it. Adding the lesser JFrame to the main JFrame's content pane gave horrible, nightmarish bugs. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JDialogs as the child windows and make sure you specify the JFrame as the owner of the dialog.